# Is there a way to extract user’s full name from HealthKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am trying to build a fitness app and I would like to build the user’s profile within the app but I would like to make it as quick and easy as possible for the user. I am able to extract the users stats such as height, body mass, birth date etc from HealthKit but is there a way for me to extract the user’s full name since the ios health app has this on it’s profile page.

I have sifted through the documentation, but so far I haven’t found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no there is no api AFAIC.

you can ask for addressbook access and read the 'me' contact

Comment: Came looking for this question because, as a user, I was hoping this was not possible. Good privacy move by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could go through all the contacts in the AddressBook and see if any of them are marked with the owner flag.

Just be aware that doing this will popup the "this app wants access to the address book" message. Also Apple isn't very keen on these kind of things. In the app review guide it is specified that an app can not use personal information without the user's permission.

You will get the username like this:

```
 var username = NSUserName()!
```

and you can use same user name for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don’t want to meddle with the address book and freak the user out. I’ll probably just ask them to enter their name instead.